# Haskell Shake with Twitch?

Tags: haskell, build, pandoc, shake-build-system

I'm switching (or trying to) from the brilliant [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/) to [haskell shake](http://shakebuild.com/) as my build system..

Only I can't figure out how to get shake to rebuild files on changes.

I could of course use inotify or a wrapper like [filewatcher](https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher) or even [watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman).

Since I'm using shake though, I was wondering how to integrate with [twitch](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/twitch) which shares the do syntax, but otherwise doesn't provide much in way of documentation..

The ultimate goal is to use pandoc for multi format documents.

The only reason tup was inadequate was because it doesn't support targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should to write your own `shake` build rules. Then, when some source file will be changed, you should to run your build rules to produce your targets.

Like this:

```
main = defaultMain $ do
  "src/*.md" |> const build

build = shakeArgs shake{shakeFiles="out"} $ do
    want ["out/foo.html", "out/foo.pdf"]

    "out/*.html" %> \out -> do
        let src = "src" </> dropDirectory1 out -<.> "md"
        cmd_ "pandoc -o" [out] src

    "out/*.pdf" %> \out -> do
        let src = "src" </> dropDirectory1 out -<.> "md"
        cmd_ "pandoc -o" [out] src
```

When a markdown file in `src` directory will be changed, then `out/foo.html` and `out/foo.pdf` will be updated.

If you want to optimize work of `shake` then you can do like this:

```
main = defaultMain $ do
  "src/*.md" |> build . dependentTargets

build targets = shakeArgs shake{shakeFiles="out"} $ do
    want targets
    ...

dependentTargets src
    | "*.md" ?== src = ["out/foo.html", "out/foo.pdf"]
    | otherwise = []
```

---

The package `twitch` recommends to use extension `OverloadedStrings` for compile code like this:

```
"src/*.md" |> ...
```

But this leads to ambiguous code in other parts of the program. For fix that, you can explicitly converting `String` to `Dep` like this:

```
import Data.String

fromString "src/*.md" |> ...
```

You can improve this code by redefining the `(|>)` operator:

```
import Data.String
import Twitch hiding ((|>))

pattern |> callback = addModify callback $ fromString pattern

"src/*.md" |> ...
```

Comment: Somehow I'm getting Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘DepM ()’
for ‘do { "src/*.md" |> const build }’

Comment: Use extension `OverloadedStrings` (`{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`) for implicitly converting `String -> Dep` or `Data.String.fromString` for explicitly converting.

Comment: This leads to `Ambiguous type variable ‘t1’ arising from the literal ‘"pandoc -o"’ prevents the constraint ‘(Data.String.IsString
                                  t1)’ from being solved.
      In the expression:
        do { let src = "src" </> dropDirectory1 out -<.> "md";
             cmd "pandoc -o" [out] src }`
Sorry if I'm getting too verbose..

Comment: I updated answer with recommendations for fix that problems.

Answer (score 1):

I use `shake` for building a web site and have wrapped it into `twitch` to rerun the shake build when some files change. The main call for the watching functions (it uses  `forkIO` to watches in two directories, and each can run shake) is bracketed; it also starts the web server.

```
mainWatch :: SiteLayout -> Port -> Path Abs Dir ->  IO ()
mainWatch layout  bakedPort bakedPath = bracketIO
        (do  -- first
            shake layout
            watchDough <-  forkIO (mainWatchDough layout)   -- calls shake
            watchTemplates <-  forkIO (mainWatchThemes layout) -- calls shake
            scotty bakedPort (site bakedPath)
            return (watchDough,watchTemplates) )
        (\(watchDough,watchTemplates) -> do -- last
                    putIOwords ["main2 end"]
                    killThread watchDough
                    killThread watchTemplates
                    return ()
            )
        (\watch -> do   -- during
                    return ()
            )
```

Hope this can be adapted to your case!